# Kendo grid pass parameters from colum to js function

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid

Can you help me, please!
I use Kendo UI MVC. I just create ClientTemplate, but I do not know how to  pass parameters correctly from my model.

```
.Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(i => i.ExtractionDate).Title(CwAppContext.GetString<GridsTitles>("lblExtractionDate")).Groupable(false).Width(150)
          .ClientTemplate("\\# if (IsWeWrite) { \\#  \\#=ExtractionDate\\#  \\#} else { \\# " +
              "<a class='issue-date-link' data-is-european-country='\\#=IsEuropeanCountry\\#' data-language-id='\\#=LanguageId\\#' data-available='\\#=IsAvailable\\#' data-doc-id='\\#=DocId\\#'>\\#=ExtractionDate\\#</a>" +
              "\\# } \\#");

          columns.Bound(i => i.IssueDate).Title(CwAppContext.GetString<GridsTitles>("ttlIssueDate")).Groupable(false);
      })
```

Finally I want to create some functions and invoke it like:

```
.ClientTemplate(IssueDateClientTemplate().ToString());
```

But my code is not correct. Can somebody explain and help me?

```
@helper IssueDateClientTemplate()
{
    <text>
        # if (IsWeWrite) {\\#:ExtractionDate\\#} else { #
        <a class='issue-date-link' data-is-european-country='\\#=IsEuropeanCountry\#'
           data-language-id='\\#=LanguageId\\#' data-available='\\#=IsAvailable\\#'
           data-doc-id='\\#=DocId\\#'>\\#=ExtractionDate\\#</a>"# }#
    </text>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Examples how to use templates when you use server or client binding:

**Client binding**
**Helper:**

```
@helper IssueDateClientTemplate()
{
    <text>
        # if(Id == 1) { #
        <a class='issue-date-link' data-is-european-country='#=Id#'>#=Id#</a>
        # } #
    </text>
}
```

**Column:**

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Name).ClientTemplate(IssueDateClientTemplate().ToString().Trim());
```

**Server binding:**
**Helper:**

```
@helper IssueDateClientTemplate(BaseData item)
{
    if (item.Id == 1)
    {
        <a class='issue-date-link' data-is-european-country='@item.Id'>@item.Id</a>
    }
}
```

**Column:**

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Template(@<text>@IssueDateClientTemplate(item)</text>);
```